# I need some help determining an AppID with regard to binding a certificate

Tags: windows

I need to install a certificate to enable https connections to an IIS database that is available solely on our local network.  It is not in the public DNS. Researching this, I found a thread on StackExchange that explains the process.  [https://serverfault.com/questions/1060268/ssl-for-devices-in-local-network]

The last comment in the thread seems to offer a solution, but toward the end of the explanation, it makes a reference to an AppID.  Can someone explain how I can find the AppID that I would need to plug into the netsh command below?

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:2222 certhash=”certificate thumbprint” appid={app Id}

Many thanks for any tips or suggestions!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537173/what-appid-should-i-use-with-netsh-exe

Comment: PowerShell native: new-guide will generate one

Comment: Hello!  In the meanwhile, I found this post on another forum, (https://dev.to/sardarmudassaralikhan/how-to-enable-https-on-iis-server-local-host-207n) which explains how to use tools in IIS to solve the problem.  I appreciate your help.